# Sounds like you need something to do

Tags: word, knowledge, connections-puzzle

What word am I thinking of? Each group will give you part of what you need.

**Group 1**
split, peel, bunch, dump

**Group 2**
Vermont, Virginia, Tennessee, Kentucky, North Carolina

**Group 3**
Merlin, Percival, Mordred, Morgana, Oberon

**Group 4**
apple, wrench, water, horse, ice cream, pencil

**Group 5**
red, yellow, white, green, blue, purple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word you are thinking of is

> Board

Group 1

> These are calls from the board game [Bananagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bananagrams)

Group 2

> These are names of streets from the [Monopoly board template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Monopoly_board_layout)

Group 3

> These are all characters from [Avalon: The Resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Resistance_(game))

Group 4

> These are all pieces in the board game [Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(game))

Group 5

> These are colours of characters from the game [Cluedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluedo)

Finally

> Take the first letter of the first answer, second of the second, etc and we spell out **BOARD**
>  Explicity,
>  **B**ananagrams
>  m**O**nopoly
>  av**A**lon
>  ope**R**ation
>  clue**D**o

Title (pointed out by SteveV)

> **BOARD** sounds like **BORED** (in need of something to do).

Comment: Naq gur gvgyr qrfpevorf n ubzbalz bs gur nafjre

Comment: @SteveV Thanks, I've added that in.